# Obsolete property doesn't raise warning when used in addition assignment

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, compiler-warnings, obsolete

In my opinion the usage of an obsolete property always needs to raise a warning. It does in most cases.

**Raises error:**

```
[Obsolete("This method is obsolete")]
public int Number { get; set; }

var address = Number.ToString();
```

**Doesn't raise error:**

```
[Obsolete("This method is obsolete")]
public string Number { get; set; }

var address = Street;
address += Number.ToString();
```

Is this a compiler bug or by design?

This is with Visual Studio 2013 (Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 12.0.40629.0, Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.34014)

Comment: Which compiler or IDE are you using?

Comment: Thanks Igby. I've updated my question.

Comment: Can be reproduced on my machine (VS 2013, v. 12.0.40629.00 Update 5). Looks like a compiler bug to me. NB: ReSharper does create a warning.